# Basemap: save figure with several time-steps and to unique file name

Tags: python, plot, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I have a netCDF file with current-data I am plotting with basemap module in Python3.5.

The file with the current data contains roughly 2000 time-steps (hourly), and I want it to plot all time-steps, and save the figure to a unique file name. Is this possible?

```
u = data.variables['u'][0,0,:,:]
v = data.variables['v'][0,0,:,:]
Where the first 0 is the time step variable.
```

Sub-question: How do I make a constant colorbar, so that the comparison between the plot will be accurate?

Comment: if you have another question post it in a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I went ahead and adapted the code you embedded to work with what your aiming to do. I don't have a way to test this, since I don't have your dataset, so comment back if this doesn't help. I have placed comments throughout that should hopefully help decipher what I've changed. Happy to answer any questions.

EDIT2: Different way to approach the consistent colorbar issue. Calculate the speeds for time step one, and use that for the color array for each plot.

```
import netCDF4
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def u_v_components(u,v,angle):
        """ Rotate the u, v vectors from model grid to east/north coords """
        u_east = (np.cos(angle)*u - np.sin(angle)*v)
        v_north = (np.sin(angle)*u + np.cos(angle)*v)
        return u_east, v_north

# Setting the map
scale  = 0.6
width  = 1800000
height = 2300000
lat_0  = 70.8
lon_0  = 25
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 10))
m = Basemap(width=width*scale,height=height*scale,
        resolution='i',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=70,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)

m.fillcontinents(color='#aaaaaa',lake_color='#cccccc')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.2)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#cccccc')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,5.),labels=[False,True,True,False])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,10.),labels=[True,False,False,True])

dataurl = '/Users/JDMac/norkyst_800m_surfcurr_MAY-JUL_2010_NordNorge_middel.nc'
data = netCDF4.Dataset(dataurl)

# I moved the angle and grid operations out of the loop since they
# only need to be done once.
#angle array in dataset
angle = data.variables['angle'][:,:]

#gridlons and gridlats tell us the lon and lat of each
# point in the grid. This is necessary for drawing on
# the map.
gridlons = data.variables['lon'][:,:]
gridlats = data.variables['lat'][:,:]

X, Y = m(gridlons, gridlats)

YY = np.arange(0, Y.shape[0], 10)
XX = np.arange(0, X.shape[1], 10)
points = np.meshgrid(YY, XX)

#current u-v component [time, depth, lon, lat]
u = data.variables['u'][0,0,:,:]
v = data.variables['v'][0,0,:,:]

#rotate current u-v components from model grid to east-north coordinates
u_east, v_north = u_v_components(u,v,angle)

#pytagoras' theorem to calculate the current velocity and direction
# Calculate speed for time step 0, then maintain this array to
# consistently colorize your vector plot.
speed = np.sqrt(u_east**2 + v_north**2)

# Iterate through the time steps, subsetting the data
# by time step as you go.
# I don't know what the time dimension in your dataset is named,
# so you may have to change it.
for time in range(data.dimensions['time'].size):
    #current u-v component [time, depth, lon, lat]
    u = data.variables['u'][time,0,:,:]
    v = data.variables['v'][time,0,:,:]

    #rotate current u-v components from model grid to east-north coordinates
    u_east, v_north = u_v_components(u,v,angle)

    # Added the cmap kwarg which will define what colormap is
    # used to color the arrows. Depending on your version of
    # matplotlib, jet or viridis is the default if cmap is not specified.
    m.quiver(X[points], Y[points],
                     u_east[points], v_north[points],
                     speed[points],
                     cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis'))

    # I recommend using the Basemap colorbar method
    # unless for some reason you need more control over all
    # of the colorbar properties. The colorbar method allwos you to
    # manipulate the relative size of the colorbar, the padding
    # between it and the axes, as well as the location on the map.
    cb = m.colorbar(mappable=plt.cgi(),
                       location='right')
    cb.set_label('Strømhastighet i m/s')

    plt.tight_layout()

    # Give each output file a unique filename
    # bbox_inches='tight' will remove as much whitespace as it can
    plt.savefig('current{}.png'.format(time),
                            bbox_inches='tight',
                            dpi = 300)
    # Clear the figure before re-use
    plt.clf()

# Garbage collection should close any open figures and datasets, but
# it's good practice to do so explicitly
plt.close('all')
data.close()
```

A few things:

1. I moved the grid operations and setting the angles array outside of the loop I added since they only need to be done once
2. I made the vector rotation piece into a function you can call each iteration of the loop
3. As you loop through the time steps, I use the same array of speeds to which matplotlib will map the colormap to (hopefully) solve your constant colorbar issue.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I get an error message when I'm trying to run the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "current.py", line 75, in <module>
    speed[points],
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Oops I missed that detail. NumPy is trying to slice the now 1-D array of speeds with a 2-D array of indices (points). I fixed that in the answer. Let me know how the results turn out since I've never used the Color argument of quiver, so I'm interested to see if my idea works!

Comment: Now I get another error message, I wish I could send you the file, but it's 12 gb. I edited my other reply with the error message, if you are curious.

Comment: I see what the problem is. I've edited my answer again to try another approach at the constant colorbar. What I'm going to do is do the speed calculation for the first subset of data, and then keep that as the speed array throughout each time step so the colorbars are comparable.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I got it to work! Only one problem:
"AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'cgi'", but when I removed it from the code it worked. What does the cgi do?

Comment: The basemap options seem to only apply to the first image (continent color etc), on the others there is only the plot of the current. Should I put the basemap options inside the for-loop?

Comment: @joddm sorry for taking so long. I mistyped! it should have been plt.get_gci() which is short for get current image mappable i.e. use the contour set etc. that I'm currently working with.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake by not putting the code to draw the Basemap inside the for loop since I call plt.clf() (clear figure) at the end of each loop. You will have to move that code inside the loop to redraw the coastlines, map boundary, etc. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

edit:

```
  File "current.py", line 75, in <module>
    speed[:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 560, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,u,v,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3712, in quiver
    ret =  ax.quiver(x,y,u,v,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4433, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py", line 460, in __init__
    self.set_UVC(U, V, C)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py", line 541, in set_UVC
    mask = ma.mask_or(mask, C.mask, copy=False, shrink=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 1693, in mask_or
    return make_mask(umath.logical_or(m1, m2), copy=copy, shrink=shrink)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7200,) (8,)
```